# Не могу обновить текст в ComboBox после смены элемента

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть такой код:

```
private void Disks_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            disks.Items.Clear();
            DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
            foreach(DriveInfo drive in allDrives)
            {
                if (drive.IsReady)
                    disks.Items.Add(drive.Name+drive.VolumeLabel);
            }
        }
```

И есть событие в котором я меняю текущий текст на отредактированный. Проблема в том что текст не меняется на элементе, хотя в свойстве котрола он поменялся:

```
private void Disks_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            disks.Text = "Тут нужно изменить текст";
        }
```

И заодно ещё один вопрос: как можно ускорить вот этот элемент:

```
 if (drive.IsReady)
```

очень долго проверяет флоппи дисковод на готовность.

Comment: В чем польза кода в этой функции? `Disks_DropDown`

Comment: Получаю в комбобокс список всех подключённых дисков. Обновляю их при каждом выпадении списка.

Comment: это и так написано в коде, я имею ввиду - зачем вы это делаете на каждое выпедение списка?

Comment: Это черновой набросок. Я застопорился на моменте с изменением текста.

Comment: Ваша первая проблема в том, что вы полностью очищаете и перезаполняете   комбобокс без конкретной причины

Comment: Вторая проблема с вопросом, что вы не указали ни технологию (WPF / WinForms), ни настройки вашего контрола, а просто 2 каких то события, так что не каждый это сможет воспроизвести

Comment: Ну а третья проблема [самая легкая](https://stackoverflow.com/a/524868/312041) - вы не можете устанавливать произвольный текст комбобоксу, а только такой текст, который есть [среди элементов в комбобоксе](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.text?view=netframework-4.8). Иначе он не обновится в интерфейсе.

Comment: Если менять текст в private void Disks_DropDown, то всё прекрасно меняется. WinForms. По сути контрол с базовыми параметрами, ничего не менялось после его создания.

Comment: А по поводу перезаполнения, то приведённый вариант использовался мной для отладки. Далее обновление будет только по требованию.

Comment: Покажите работающий пример. Сейчас когда я пишу `disks.Text = "Тут нужно изменить текст";`, на форме не меняется ничего.

Comment: private void Disks_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            disks.Items.Clear();
            DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
            foreach(DriveInfo drive in allDrives)
            {
                if (drive.IsReady)
                    disks.Items.Add(drive.Name+drive.VolumeLabel);
            }
            disks.Text = "Тут нужно изменить текст";
        }

Comment: Решение: disks.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => disks.Text = "Нужный текст"));

Comment: Вероятно, текст можно изменить, пока не выбран item